# Manipulating a list in a list of lists that matches user input in Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a fictional database of missing persons. The database is a list of lists with the *'headers': Last Name, First Name, DoB, Phone Number, Status, Missing Since, and Found On.*

Besides adding new entries, I want users to be able to update an existing entry by providing the *Last Name and DoB* of the entry they wish to update. I am now formulating this as follows, but am having trouble getting this to work.

for e.g.

user input: `'Pelgrim', '01/01/1900'`

desired output: `['Pelgrim', 'Richard', '01/01/1900', '12345643', ...]`

```
correct_entry = False
while correct_entry == False:
    user_query = input(
        "Please provide the last name and DoB (DD/MM/YYYY) of the entry you want to update, separated by a comma: "
    )
    user_query_list = [x.strip() for x in user_query.split(",")]
    user_query_list[0] = str(user_query_list[0]).capitalize()

    for sublist in missing_persons:
        if user_query_list[0] == sublist[0] and user_query_list[1] == sublist[2]:
            print(
                "We have found the following entry to match the last name and DoB you provided: \n"
            )
            print(sublist)
        else:
            print(
                "We could not find an entry to match the information you provided. Please try again."
            )
```

Comment: Welcome. Apply some formatting to your code and provide us input data and desired output.

Comment: Can you please try to provide a [mre]?